# Isochoric gas process taking heat from surrounding environment

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, cooling, cryogenics

this is a $pV$-diagram of Stirling cooler:

[image]

A => B and C => D processes are isothermal, co temperature in D is same as temperature after cooling on high temperature side. Although, temperature of surrounding environment lowers and gas temperature raises. How is it possible to transfer heat to warmer gas from surrounding environment? I know formula:
$$\frac{p_1}{T_1}=\frac{p_2}{T_2}$$
It's noticeable that it works in direction to produce work but I don't understand what is motivation of surrounding environment to transfer heat to working gas if not temperature difference?

Thank you for your ideas and answers.

Comment: Have you considered that the surrounding environment has a much greater mass times heat capacity than the system, or, alternatively, consists of a combination of liquid and solid at the melting point, so that its temperature does not change when it absorbs or gives off heat?

Comment: Surrounding environmen is something like container with air to be liquified. You are right that temperature doesn't change during melting or solidification but temperature have to be dropped down to melting temperature before and at that moment there is no solidizing process. Temperature is even still the same as temperature of cooler so something like 300 K.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that this surrounding environment is really part of your system, and that a larger environment surrounds this.